# Use JavaScript to choose random images on page load, but make this random image load a second specific image with it

Tags: javascript, image

So I have a website where we have a background image that we change every now and then. We also have a blurred version of the image that we create which is set behind so when the window, etc, is too large, the blurred image extends out to the sides. See screenshot

[image]

We want the main front image to randomly pick on every page load from a set of 5 images, but the specific blurred image for that main image needs to also be behind it. What piece of code could be used to

1. pick a random image to show, and
2. then have the corresponding blur image load behind it?

Comment: 1: A little bit of JS will be enough
2: No code / script needed, simply have your blurred image there with plain html or css

Answer (score 0):

The piece of code should be something like this (you can paste it anywhere in your HTML file):

```
<script>
  document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
    var images = ['sky.jpg', 'ocean.jpg', 'mountain.jpg', 'road.jpg', 'food.jpg'];
    var blurredImages = ['sky_b.jpg', 'oce_b.jpg', 'mou_b.jpg', 'roa_b.jpg', 'foo_b.jpg'];

    var rnd = Math.floor(Math.random() * 5);

    document.body.style.backgroundImage = images[rnd];
    document.getElementById('mainDiv').style.backgroundImage = blurredImages[rnd];
  });
</script>
```

**Steps**

- Put the images and the equivalent blurred images into two arrays
- Generates a random value by calling `Math.random()`
- Use the generated random value as the index of the images' arrays, and set them as background